# Printing arrays elements using recursion

Tags: ada

I am learning Ada programming language and I can admit that it's strongly typed. In this code, I am trying to ask the user to enter 4 integers and then by using recursion, print out these numbers. However, I am facing trouble writing a recursion subprogram for it and wonder if I can get any suggestions on how to write it correctly?

```
with Ada.Text_IO;                    use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;            use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Dugga is
Y: Natural; 
type arr is
 array (1..4) of Natural;
A:arr;

function Recurs(Item: in Natural) return Natural is
begin
  if Item >= 1 then    
    return Get(Item ); --Error: Context requires function call, found procedure name
end if;         
  end Recurs;   

begin
Y:=Recurs(arr);  --Error: expected type "Standard.Integer. Found type: arr 
end Dugga;
```

> Warnings: Program_error may be raised at run time
> "return" statement missing following this statement
> Error: Missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to get

Comment: Your example neither prints the numbers, nor utilize any recursion. Your error messages are quite clear; `Get` is a procedure, not a function.  The parameter to `Recurs` (which does not recurse), is of the wrong type. You're missing a `return` statement in the function body.

Comment: Great that you admit that Ada is strongly typed. Who knew. A shame that your code shows no indication that you understand what this means.

Answer (score 5):

You appear to be confused about what a recursive subprogram is. A recursive subprogram calls itself unless a termination condition is reached.
If your subprogram calls itself before printing the array element the array elements will be printed in reverse order. If your subprogram calls itself after printing the array element the array elements will be printed in the order they are entered.

```
with Ada.Text_Io; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   subtype Idx is integer range 1..4;
   type Arr is array (Idx) of Integer;
   procedure Print(Nums : Arr; Index : Idx) is
   begin
      Put (Nums(Index)'Image);
      if Index = Nums'Last then
         New_Line;
      else
         Print(Nums, Index + 1);
      end if;
   end Print;
   
   A : Arr := (1, 2, 3, 4);
begin
   Print(A, A'First);
end Main;
```

The program above declares an array type and creates an instance of that array type.
The procedure Print is a recursive procedure that prints the value of an array at the specified index value. The procedure then checks the index value. If the index value is the last index value for the array the procedure calls New_Line, otherwise it calls Print with second parameter being Index + 1.

Answer (score 3):

For any recursive algorithm you need to have some sort of control logic (IF, CASE, etc.) that decides between calling the function again with a **different** input (and returning that result with the potential result of this call) or otherwise returning a **final** value.

A couple of things.

1. You say our end game is to use recursion to "print" the values, so your recursive operation only needs to be a procedure.  It doesn't need to return anything, it just needs to print something each time it runs.  One way to do this is print the first element of the array and then recall the procedure with just the remaining elements.  If there are no elements, don't print anything and leave the procedure.
2. In order to do this, I would recommend passing in the whole array instead of a single value (like your version does).  Each time you recursively call the function, you shorten the array until there is no array left.  To do this though, you need to adjust your array type to be any potential size, not just 1..4, so that you can use that to end the recursion.

Start with making an array type:

```ada
type Natural_Array is array (Positive range <>) of Natural;
```

Now change the specification of your function to a procedure that uses that type.

```ada
procedure Recurse(Numbers: in Natural_Array);
```

The last part is implementing the recursion:

```ada
procedure Recurse(Numbers: in Natural_Array) is
begin
    -- See if the array has any elements first
    if Numbers'Length > 0 then    
    
        -- There are elements in the array, so print the 
        -- first one. This is why we use Numbers'First 
        -- as the index
        Put_Line(Numbers(Numbers'First)'Image);
        
        -- Now that we printed the first number, lets
        -- only pass in the remaining elements in the array
        -- here.  This is where the "recursion" happens
        -- as it calls this function again with a reduced
        -- input set.  Eventually we'll pass in an 
        -- empty array once the last element is printed
        -- above.
        Recurse(Numbers(Numbers'First+1..Numbers'Last));
    else
    
        -- Here there weren't any eleemnts in the array
        -- left, so lets just end the recursion by 
        -- doing nothing
        null;
    end if;         
end Recurse;
```

Here's the full compilable example:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Hello is
    
    type Natural_Array is array (Positive range <>) of Natural;
   
    procedure Recurse(Numbers: in Natural_Array) is
    begin
        -- See if the array has any elements first
        if Numbers'Length > 0 then    
        
            -- There are elements in the array, so print the 
            -- first one. This is why we use Numbers'First 
            -- as the index
            Put_Line(Numbers(Numbers'First)'Image);
            
            -- Now that we printed the first number, lets
            -- only pass in the remaining elements in the array
            -- here.  This is where the "recursion" happens
            -- as it calls this function again with a reduced
            -- input set.  Eventually we'll pass in an 
            -- empty array once the last element is printed
            -- above.
            Recurse(Numbers(Numbers'First+1..Numbers'Last));
        else
        
            -- Here there weren't any eleemnts in the array
            -- left, so lets just end the recursion by 
            -- doing nothing
            null;
        end if;         
    end Recurse;  
    
    A : Natural_Array(1..4) := (1,2,3,4);

begin
    Recurse(A);  
end Hello;
```